# Adobe Air: version number does not start with digit

Tags: linux, air, ubuntu-11.04, dpkg

i'm installing `Adobe Air` in `Ubuntu v11.04`. The installation process is successful. But when I tried to install an `Adobe Air` application, errors occur.

Here's  the usual error I've got from my `.appdata/Adobe/AIR/Logs/Install.log`:

```
[airinstall:20544][ERR] Error occurred during rpm install operation; 
beginning rollback:ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false 
eventPhase=2 text=" error: dpkg: error processing /tmp/FlashTmp.FbSCaL/setup.deb
(--install):; parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 2 package
'airapp.89645ff9cb451f3d45f5ea98a81376d1be111ef6.1':; error in Version string
'V5.01.25.A04111': version number does not start with digit;
Errors were encountered while processing:; /tmp/FlashTmp.FbSCaL/setup.deb" 
errorID=1]
```

I've followed every instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu-corner.com/2011/06/how-to-install-adobe-air-on-ubuntu-11-04-x64/) and install as root. What did I've done wrong?
According to some forums I've read, this has something to do with the `version policy` of `dpkg` but I don't know how to configured `dpkg` to ignore `versioning`. Anyone knows how to solve this? Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: by the way, I have downloaded `Adobe Air` from this [link](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/853/cpsid_85304.html).

Comment: changing the version of my `air` app solves the problem BUT the auto-update for my app is affected. I still wanted to force `dpkg` to accept my `version-number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully installed my `air` app with no `version number does not start with digit` error. I just downgraded my `dpkg-1.16.0` to `dpkg-1.15.8` using the ff command:

```
dpkg --force-downgrade -i /pathofnewdpkg/dpkg_1.15.8.4ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

I have downloaded the older package [here](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/55202069/dpkg_1.15.8.4ubuntu3_i386.deb).

Since the version-policy is enforced on the current version of `dpkg`, the `dpkg-1.16.0`, installing an `air` app that violates this versioning policy of `Debian` will result to an error.

I have documented the resolution on my [newbie dev blog](http://ruidevnotes.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/setup-adobe-air-and-handle-air-apps-version-number-error-ubuntu-11-04/).